# JQuery ajax post works only the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Edit (I have solved this):

---

I have figured this out - I was returning a string (integer.ToString("C")) in the JSON data which I then placed into my textbox. Upon clicking the submit button, it was trying to parse the currency (now: "£2.99") into an integer (currentAmount is an integer in my bid object), which of course became 0, which resulted in my bid form not being able to serialise this data.

---

Currently I have an Ajax request through JQuery which performs a postback on my BID controller method. The method returns some JSON which lets me update my HTML with current values, such as Current Price, Bid Count, and the Next Recommended Bid Price.

My problem is, once I click the submit button, the ajax makes the post and correctly returns the data I expect. However, when I click the Submit button a second time, the bid passed pass through to my controller from my View doesn't have my form data (amount is now 0, when I can see it isn't on the page)

Why is this? I am using entity framework to save my auction and bid.

Here is my code:

**Controller BID Post**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Bid(Bid bid)
    {
        var db = new AuctionsDataContext();
        var auction = db.Auctions.Find(bid.AuctionId);

        bid.Username = User.Identity.Name;
        auction.Bids.Add(bid);
        auction.CurrentPrice = bid.Amount;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new
        {
            CurrentPrice = bid.Amount.ToString("C"),
            BidCount = auction.BidCount,
            Number = (bid.Amount + 1).ToString("C")
        });

    }
```

**My BID form on Auction.cshtml**

```
    <p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Bid", "Auctions"))
    {
        var lowestBidAmount = auction.CurrentPrice.GetValueOrDefault(auction.StartPrice) + 1;

        <span>
            Bid: $@Html.TextBox("amount", lowestBidAmount)
            @Html.ValidationMessage("amount")
        </span>

        @Html.Hidden("auctionId", auction.Id)

        <input class="post-bid" type="submit" value="Bid" />
    }
</p>
```

**My Ajax script**

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.post-bid').on("click", function () {
            var form = $(this).parent("form");

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize()
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    var template = $('#current-price-template').clone().html();

                    var html = template
                        .replace('{{CurrentPrice}}', data.CurrentPrice)
                        .replace('{{BidCount}}', data.BidCount);

                    $('.current-price').replaceWith(html);

                    $('#amount').val(data.Number);
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert("Your big has been rejected");
                });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you've solved it by yourself, you should write out an answer and mark it so the question falls off the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: Apologies, I'm new here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out - I was returning a string (integer.ToString("C")) in the JSON data which I then placed into my textbox. Upon clicking the submit button, it was trying to parse the currency (now: "£2.99") into an integer (currentAmount is an integer in my bid object), which of course became 0, which resulted in my bid form not being able to serialise this data.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the content of the template but my guess would be that you are replacing the content to which to click event is attached and so when you replace the dom element you lose the click event binding. This type of binding is called directly bound.

To achieve the type of functionality you want you need to use the delegated style of binding where the click event handler is bound to a parent element or higher and a selector parameter in the binding call identifies which elements to process the click event for. This type of event binding is called delegated. When the content is replaced the handler remains and is available to handle the events from the child elements identified by the selector.

In your case something like.

```
form.on('click', '.post-bid',eventHandler);
```

For a more detailed description please the documentation for the jquery .on statement
http://api.jquery.com/on/